# Request repr() unavailable in Django 500 error email: how do I debug how to get the full stack trace?

Tags: python, django, django-email

Normally the django '**mail_admins**' logging handler will email you 500 errors to ADMINS along with a useful stacktrace of what happened.

But for some reason I'm getting error emails with

```
Request repr() unavailable
```

at the bottom of the email!   Anyone know how to figure out why this is happening?  (So I can get stacktraces to fix bugs with!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it is a question long time ago, the answer here might help others in the future. It's important to pass in request through extra.

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.error(
    logging.traceback.format_exc(),
    extra={
        'status_code': 500, # or else
        'request': request
    }
)
```